# SQLSTATE[42000] error in my Insert Query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Admittedly I have not touched MYSQL for a while so please forgive me if this is a simple error. I am trying to insert data using a PDO query but I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access     violation: 1064 You have
> an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ( '',
> '/dYtAyg4vD88hIfrR1VKDnVGhnE6.jpg', '106646', 'The'

Here is my query

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `cache_movies` (
        api_adult, 
        api_backdrop_path, 
        api_id, 
        api_original_title, 
        api_release_date, 
        api_poster_path, 
        api_popularity, 
        api_title, 
        api_video, 
        api_vote_average, 
        api_vote_count, 
    ) VALUES (
        :api_adult, 
        :api_backdrop_path, 
        :api_id, 
        :api_original_title, 
        :api_release_date, 
        :api_poster_path, 
        :api_popularity, 
        :api_title, 
        :api_video, 
        :api_vote_average, 
        :api_vote_count, 
    )");
$query->execute(array(
    ':api_adult' => $results['results'][0]['adult'],
    ':api_backdrop_path' => $results['results'][0]['backdrop_path'],
    ':api_id' => $results['results'][0]['id'],
    ':api_original_title' => $results['results'][0]['original_title'],
    ':api_release_date' => $results['results'][0]['release_date'],
    ':api_poster_path' => $results['results'][0]['poster_path'],
    ':api_popularity' => $results['results'][0]['popularity'],
    ':api_title' => $results['results'][0]['title'],
    ':api_video' => $results['results'][0]['video'],
    ':api_vote_average' => $results['results'][0]['vote_average'],
    ':api_vote_count' => $results['results'][0]['vote_count']
));
```

I used a online SQL validator and it said the error was on the line where `) VALUES (` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the comma at end of these lines:

```
 api_vote_count,
```

and

```
:api_vote_count,
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove these commas:

[image: commas]